# Show Windows 7 Windows Picture Viewer in Windows 8

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe4

On Windows 8 I tried to run the code shown below to show the old Windows 7 Picture Viewer, but it returns an error.   On Windows 8 I can find C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll but I think that is the newer Windows 8 metro app.  I think the older Windows Picture Viewer is 'c:\windows\system32\shimgvw.dll.  I'd like to preview the image with the desktop application style rather than Metro.

I tried both, but both return that the file does not have a program associated with it?
What am I messing up?

```
var
SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
ExitCode: DWORD;
ExecuteFile, ParamString, StartInString: string;

ExecuteFile:='c:\windows\system32\shimgvw.dll';
FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0) ;
SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
with SEInfo do begin
  fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  Wnd := Application.Handle;
  lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile);
  nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  lpParameters := PChar('ImageView_Fullscreen');
end;
if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then begin
repeat
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
 until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
   ShowMessage('Windows Picture Viewer terminated') ;
 end
    else ShowMessage('Error starting Windows Picture Viewer') ;
```

I have not used ShellExecuteEx before so the basis for the code came from [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm).

Comment: Can you be more precise than "it returns an error"? And if you want to preview an image, why are you hardcoding the application that will display the image? Why don't you pass the image to the shell and ask it to preview it?

Comment: Windows displays the error message at ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) and the ExitCode after the message in the debugger is 69627776.

Comment: When I pass the image name to the shell it runs the metro app.

Comment: Your existing code runs a busy loop. You want `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. The ExitCode is never assigned because you never call `GetExitCodeProcess` when the if fails. Call `GetLastError` to find out why `ShellExecuteEx` fails.

Comment: Also, I assumed that the code in the question does what you intend on Windows 7. But on closer inspection, that's not the case.

Comment: errorcode is 1, message is incorrect function

Comment: I only have win 8 now... in the past I used a shellexexuteassociatedfile function.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the shell's choose-default functionality? Right-click > Open with > Choose default program > Windows Photo Viewer

Comment: I think Jonathan Potter has got the idea of what you want. Do be warned that what you are proposing is very brittle.

Comment: open with ... yes that is what I am trying to accomplish but with code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shimgvw.dll` is a DLL. You can't run a DLL directly, you have to load the DLL and call an exported function within it.

If you look at the registry on a Windows 7 system you'll see this is what Explorer does to invoke the Photo Viewer:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

`rundll32.exe` is a tool that comes with Windows that exists purely to load a DLL and invoke a function within it. So you can either leverage `rundll32.exe` to do this, or load the DLL with `LoadLibrary()`, find the function export with `GetProcAddress()` and call the function yourself.

(and note also that on Windows 7, it's `PhotoViewer.dll` that contains the Photo Viewer, not `shimgvw.dll`. I don't know what the situation is on Windows 8).